# React Storybook unable to render a story

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am trying to create documentation with a storybook folder containing topics. But getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to render story ... as the component annotation is missing from the default export
```

**Migration.stories.mdx**

```
import { Meta, Story} from '@storybook/addon-docs';

<Meta title="Documentation / Visual Update Migration" />

# Migrating

<Story name="Card" />

## Card

-   Text
-   Text

<Story name="Container" />

## Container

-   Text
-   Text
```

All these cause Story marks, but if I remove them, there won't be refs in the sidebar

**Expected**: [image: expected path]

So, the path and side bar load correctly, but the content on click does not load giving the error.

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to render story documentation-visual-update-migration--card as the component annotation is missing from the default export ...
Uncaught Error: Unable to render story documentation-visual-update-migration--container as the component annotation is missing from the default export ...
```

Plus

```
2 The above error occurred in the <storyFn> component ...
```

And

```
POST http://localhost:6006/runtime-error 404 (Not Found)
POST http://localhost:6006/runtime-error 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `<Story ... />`. `Story` wants something inside it.

**Fix:** `<Story ...>{''}</Story>`